# Devexpress Scheduler Selected days Coming Wrongly

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I'm developing a web application using DevExpress (not the one AspMvcx) and the .NET Framework with MVC. I'm working on a scheduler functionality similar to an event calendar. However, I've encountered an issue where, when I select a range of 3 days by sliding, the pop-up that appears that I've only selected 1 day, which is incorrect. In reality, I have selected more than one day. Could you help me wotj this problem, please?

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().Scheduler()
            //.DataSource(Model)
            .TimeZone("America/Los_Angeles")
            .TextExpr("Text")
            .StartDateExpr("StartDate")
            .EndDateExpr("EndDate")
            .Views(new[] {
                 SchedulerViewType.TimelineDay,
                 SchedulerViewType.TimelineWeek,
                 SchedulerViewType.TimelineWorkWeek,
                 SchedulerViewType.TimelineMonth
            })
            .CurrentView(SchedulerViewType.TimelineMonth)
            .CurrentDate(new DateTime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0))
            .FirstDayOfWeek(FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday)
            .StartDayHour(8)
            .EndDayHour(20)
            .CellDuration(60)
            .Groups(new[] { "Priority" })
            .Resources(res =>
            {
                res.Add()
                    .FieldExpr("OwnerId")
                    .AllowMultiple(true)
                    .Label("Owner")
                    .UseColorAsDefault(true)
                    .DataSource(new[] {
            new { id = 1, text = "Samantha Bright", color = "#cb6bb2" },
            new { id = 2, text = "John Heart", color = "#56ca85" },
            new { id = 3, text = "Todd Hoffman", color = "#1e90ff" },
            new { id = 4, text = "Sandra Johnson", color = "#ff9747" }
                    });

                res.Add()
                    .FieldExpr("Priority")
                    .AllowMultiple(false)
                    .Label("Priority")
                    .DataSource(new[] {
            new { id = "Low", text = "Low Priority", color = "#1e90ff" },
            new { id = "High", text = "High Priority", color = "#ff9747" }
                    });
            })
            .Height(580)
    )
```